# Can not see 'web' folder after installing drupal using composer from git project

Tags: drupal, composer-php

I have been starting Drupal project with composer using git few times so far and always have 'web' folder in the newly created files structure.

Source of the command: https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project

Need a help why I do not have 'web' folder created after trying to start new Drupal project using composer from git using standard:

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev my_directory --no-interaction
```

I was expecting 'web' folder within newly created files with Drupal core files ready to install. They are not.

Files in 'my_directory' after running the above command:

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 ski  ski   4096 Sep  4 12:23 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root  4096 Sep  4 12:23 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 ski  ski   2474 Sep  4 12:23 composer.json
drwxr-xr-x 4 ski  ski   4096 Sep  4 12:23 drush
-rw-r--r-- 1 ski  ski    746 Sep  4 12:23 .env.example
drwxr-xr-x 8 ski  ski   4096 Sep  4 12:23 .git
-rw-r--r-- 1 ski  ski    466 Sep  4 12:23 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 ski  ski  18046 Sep  4 12:23 LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 ski  ski    414 Sep  4 12:23 load.environment.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 ski  ski    481 Sep  4 12:23 phpunit.xml.dist
-rw-r--r-- 1 ski  ski   6495 Sep  4 12:23 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 3 ski  ski   4096 Sep  4 12:23 scripts
-rw-r--r-- 1 ski  ski   1644 Sep  4 12:23 .travis.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to install some php dependencies. I also missed composer error messages. After that Drupal installs normally.

You can find all php dependencies here:

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-drupal-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 0):

Normally it should work by following https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#drupal-composer-drupal-project "To do a modified install:" paragraph.

To do that:

1. Run composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev my_site_name_dir --no-interaction --no-install
2. Change directories to my_site_name_dir and edit the composer.json file to suit your needs
3. Run composer install to download Drupal 8 and all its dependencies.

WEB folder is created with composer install command.

Thanks